# Is it possible to use "authorized_keys" to ssh into Cisco ASA 5510

Tags: ssh, cisco-asa

I have created multiple ssh accounts on a Cisco ASA 5510. Users login with a password and everything works fine. I would now like to use the authorized_keys feature of ssh so that users can log into the ASA without a password. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Cisco's just starting to clue in to public key authentication in IOS version 15, but that's no help for the ASA line.  This is, unfortunately, not possible.